# dict.get() for each incidence in a multidimensional dict with python

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

```
d=[{'a':{'b':[]}},{'a':{'b':{'c':[]}}},{'a':{'b':{'c':[],'d':[],'e':[]}}}]
```

I want some thing to returns the value of `'c'` or `'d'` or `'e'` for each incidence in `d` which is like:

```
for i in d:
 print(i.get('a',{}).get('b',{}).get('c','None')
```

However, not every `i` in `d` has `'b'` as a `dict`, some `i['a']['b']` is `None` or `list`, so `dict.get('c',None)` can not be performed. Though I can 
use `if i['a']['b']!= None` for each key, but I have to many keys like `['b']` ,
Is there any cleaver method to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get the key and handle any exceptions:

```
d = [{'a':{'b':[]}},{'a':{'b':{'c':[]}}},{'a':{'b':{'c':[],'d':[],'e':[]}}}]
for i in d:
    try:
        print(i['a']['b']['c'])
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, now I am trying to loop though every incidence and add each to a new `list =[{'c':[]},{'c':[]},{'c':[],'d':[],'e':[]}]`